# Remote desktop doesn't works after upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, remote-desktop, vnc

I worked for many years with ubuntu nas server. 
Now last week I updated my server from 13:10 to 14:04. 
That in itself went well except Remote Desktop. 
The server is in the attic and I control it from my work PC thru VNC. 
After the update, this no longer works and VNC gives the following message: No supported authentication methods!

I have vnc server installed as a separate application, but I also get the same error message. 
When I look at my settings, everything is still the same.

Does anyone know how I can "fix" it without reinstall ubuntu?

Thanks for the help.

Grt JayDee

Comment: Same problem here.  I love how stuff just inexplicably breaks with every update.

Answer (score 7):

Seems that vino was [changed to require encryption by default](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728267#c3), but only supports old encryption methods that are not commonly available.

This is a workaround till they fix it:

1. Install dconf-editor: `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
2. Start it.
3. Navigate to: org > gnome > desktop > remote-access
4. Disable "require-encryption"

(from [this thread](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/remote-desktop-sharing-in-ubuntu-14-04/1640) on discourse).

Other way to fix it is disable vino and only use x11vnc server.
x11vnc will work as long as no other desktop screening or screen sharing program is active.

Comment: I can confirm this fixed my problem trying to connect via iPad using Mocha VNC. Thanks so much! 

EDIT: I should say that the first method (dconf-editor) is what worked.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. `~> dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/require-encryption
false
~> dconf read /desktop/gnome/remote-access/enabled
false
~> gsettings get org.gnome.Vino require-encryption
false`  Real VNC Viewer still says "The connection was refused by the host computer"

Comment: actually I had to open vino-preferences on the server and re-enable everything that somehow got turned off.